# Fetch names from another table, the ids of which are stored in a column in csv format in the primary table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables - user and modules.

In the modules table I have two columns - module_id and module_name.

The user table has a column called as user_modules in which I store the modules that he can access in csv format.

for ex. There are two modules in the module table

```
module_id    module_name

1            Manage Books
2            Manage Videos
```

the user_modules column (in the user table) for a typical user would look like this

```
user_modules

1,2
```

Now the query that I use to fetch the module_name is

"Select module_name from modules where module_id in (Select user_modules from user where user_id = 1)" - Output: Manage Books

This returns the name of only the first module.

On the other hand, these queries works perfectly fine -

"Select module_name from modules where module_id in (1,2)" - Output: Manage Books, Manage Videos

"Select user_modules from user where user_id = 1" - Output: 1,2,3

What can be done to fetch all the module names in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select user.user_id, module_name from module 
inner join user on find_in_set(module.module_id, user.user_modules) is not null
```

should work. If user ID (string) is in the user_modules(string), then find_in_set returns the position. If it is not, it returns null.

or modify your query

'Select module_name from modules where module_id in (Select user_modules from user where user_id = 1)" - Output: Manage Books

to:

```
Select module_name from modules 
where 
find_in_set(module_id, (Select user_modules from user where user_id = 1)) is not null
```

Comment: no problem; unfortunately I too had to deal with concatenated IDs